# generating function and lucas numbers

Tags: combinatorics

Defines the sequence $l$.

$l_n = l_{n−1} + l_{n−2}$, for all $n \ge 2$.

So the ﬁrst few members of the sequence are: $2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 11, 18\;.$

Find the generating function for this sequence and deduce the following formula

$$l_n =\left(\frac{1 − \sqrt5}2\right)^n +\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt5}2\right)^n\;.$$

After some calculation I got the generating function

$g(x)={x-2\over x^2+x-1} =2+x+3x^2+4x^3\cdots$

Comment: This is just a very minor variation on the corresponding problem for Fibonacci numbers. Have you seen that one worked out? It would not surprise me at all if it were in your text or lecture notes.

Comment: I have worked out my generating function.   I have split it up into partial fractions. I just don't know how to deduce to the following above?

Comment: Why don’t you add your generating function to the question, and we’ll take it from there.

Answer (score 3):

As is customary, I’ve used $L_n$ for the $n$-th Lucas number rather than $l_n$.

You have

$$g(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}L_nx^n=\frac{x-2}{x^2+x-1}\;.$$

It’s a little more convenient to multiply numerator and denominator by $-1$ before splitting into partial fractions:

$$\frac{2-x}{1-x-x^2}=\frac{A}{1-\varphi x}+\frac{B}{1-\widehat\varphi x}\;,$$

where $\varphi=\frac12(1+\sqrt5)$ and $\widehat\varphi=\frac12(1-\sqrt5)$. (You should check that $(1-\varphi x)(1-\widehat\varphi x)$ really is $1-x-x^2$.) Solve for $A$ and $B$ in the usual way: $A(1-\widehat\varphi x)+B(1-\varphi x)=2-x$, so $A+B=2$, and $\widehat\varphi A+\varphi B=1$. This system is easily solved, and we find that $A=B=1$. Thus,

$$g(x)=\frac1{1-\varphi x}+\frac1{1-\widehat\varphi x}\;.$$

Recall that $\frac1{1-u}=\sum_{n\ge 0}u^n$:

$$\sum_{n\ge 0}L_nx^n=g(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}(\varphi x)^n+\sum_{n\ge 0}(\widehat\varphi x)^n=\sum_{n\ge 0}\varphi^nx^n+\sum_{n\ge 0}\widehat\varphi^nx^n\;.\tag{1}$$

Now just combine the two summations on the right of $(1)$ into a single summation and equate coefficients with the summation on the left of $(1)$ to get your closed form for $L_n$.

Comment: Just too confirm?  Doing what you said at the bottom what am supposed to deduce at the top?

Comment: @Raj: If correctly you do what I said at the bottom, you’ll deduce the closed form for $L_n$ given in your question.

Comment: Thank you so much,  I have been stuck on this all day!

Comment: @Raj: You’re very welcome.

Comment: I just was expanding what u said. And i get a=sqrt5/5 +1 and b=-sqrt5 +1...Help?

Comment: @Raj: I don’t understand; what are your $a$ and $b$ for? How are you getting them?

Comment: Isnt ur a and b ur partial fractions?  Where you have put 1? If you work it out?

Comment: @Raj: They’re my $A$ and $B$? Check that $\varphi\widehat\varphi=-1$. Multiply $\widehat\varphi A+\varphi B=1$ by $\varphi$ to get $-A+\varphi^2 B=\varphi$ and add to $A+B=2$ to get $(\varphi^2+1)B=\varphi+2$. Now check that $\varphi^2=\varphi+1$, so that $\varphi^2+1=\varphi+2$, and you’ll see that $B=1$. Once you have that, it’s clear that $A=1$.

Comment: Oh my god am so sorry,  I was making a numerical mistake

Comment: @Raj: No problem; I’ve certainly made my share over the years!

Answer (score 2):

Let $$g(x)=h_0+h_1x+h_2x^2+\cdots+h_nx^n+\cdots$$ $$-xg(x)=-h_0x-h_1x^2-h_2x^3-\cdots-h_nx^{n+1}-\cdots$$ $$-x^2g(x)=-h_0x^2-h_1x^3-h_2x^4-\cdots-h_nx^{n+2}-\cdots.$$ Adding we obtain $$(1-x-x^2)g(x)=h_0+(h_1-h_o)x+(h_2-h_1-h_0)x^2+\cdots.$$ Since $l_0=2$ and $l_1=1$ we now have $$g(x)={2\over 1-x-x^2}-{x\over 1-x-x^2}.$$ Let $1-x-x^2=(1-q_1x)(1-q_2x)$ so that $$g(x)={2-x\over (1-q_1x)(1-q_2x)}$$ where $q_1={1+\sqrt5\over 2}$ and $q_2={1-\sqrt5\over 2}$. Using partial fractions $${2-x\over (1-q_1x)(1-q_2x)}={A\over 1-q_1x}+{B\over 1-q_2x}$$ we obtain $A=1$ and $B=1$. So $${1\over 1-q_1x}+{1\over 1-q_2x}.$$Now using the geometric series we have $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (q_1x)^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty (q_2x)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty[(q_1)^n+(q_2)^n]x^n.$$ Thus $$l_n =\left(\frac{1 − \sqrt5}2\right)^n +\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt5}2\right)^n\;.$$

Comment: Once again? How are a and b 1? Once working it out using partial fractions you do noy get 1?

Comment: Oh my god am so sorry,  I was making a numerical mistake!

Comment: No worries. It took me a bit of time to do this problem too.